# Hyper-V Guest RDP keeps asking wrong credentials

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, rdp, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services

I have 3 W2008 R2 Guests running inside a w2008 R2 Hyper-V Host. All three VMs are part of a domain, All with RDP enabled, the machines have the following names and ports

HOST1 3389

VM1   3401
VM2   3402
VM3   3403

Problem, I can connect to all machines remotely except VM2,"using the domain credentials". I use my.remoteserver.com:3402 to connect to VM2, it fails to login and keeps asking for password (using domain credentials), but if I use the credentials of the host machine (discovered that accidently), which is not part of the domain and has a different password, it logs and in and gets me to the desktop, totally bypassing domain credentials. Yet when I am on the desktop I am actually logged on to the domain.

I also tried RDP from a 4th PC (not mentioned above) on the same network, I login using domain credentials. The problem occurs only when I do this from outside of my network. Obviously there is something in the Host machine that I am overlooking, I have verified and reverified the router and everthing I can think of with no luck, any suggestion would be a great help, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions and maybe a better way to get to those machines, as well as a guess about your login issue. (Feel free to ignore the advice if the suggestions don't apply to your setup, they might be useable to someone else)

Consider using Terminal Services Gateway (Remote Desktop Gateway) as opposed to exposing your servers directly.  This would give you a gateway to access machines behind your firewall without exposing them directly outside of your network.  Just adds that little extra layer.  Great part about this is that you can hit the machines directly via Remote Desktop Connection.  Though, this is not supported on any client other than windows and select iphone/ipad/android clients as far as I know. (ie..Mac RDP does not support it)

Another way could be to use HyperV Manager on the primary machine to access the VM consoles directly allowing you to close off the RDP completely to all but a single machine.

As far as your being unable to login.  Try to login to the VM locally and see if the credentials you are providing work locally.  If they do, then dig into the remote access in the VM and verify that user has remote permissions as well.

Good luck..  I can offer more specific advice if you need help with the suggestions...